# Block Updates for One Package in Microsoft Store Without Stopping All Automatic Updates

Tags: windows-11, samsung, microsoft-store

I want to keep a specific version of a program (Samsung Notes), but even though I didn't install it through the Microsoft Store, it is updated by the Microsoft Store. Thus, I had to disable the automatic updates for all applications in the Microsoft Store settings.

Is there any way to just stop updating that application and not all of them? Or maybe to remove it from the store.

I am on Windows 11 Pro 23H2, with Microsoft Store version 22401.1401.7.0. The application in question is Samsung Notes 4.3.150.0.

**Update**

I have tried the following, in PowerShell 7 with admin privileges.

```
PS C:\> Get-AppxPackage -Name "*SamsungNotes*"

RunspaceId             : 0ad217f0-2b1b-4d9d-98c7-80d60483b588
Name                   : SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCoLtd.SamsungNotes
Publisher              : CN=14C847C8-791E-46EB-9C0D-7CADAF31C930
PublisherId            : wyx1vj98g3asy
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 4.3.150.0
PackageFamilyName      : SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCoLtd.SamsungNotes_wyx1vj98g3asy
PackageFullName        : SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCoLtd.SamsungNotes_4.3.150.0_x64__wyx1vj98g3asy
InstallLocation        : C:\Program
                         Files\WindowsApps\SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCoLtd.SamsungNotes_4.3.150.0_x64__wyx1vj98g3asy
IsFramework            : False
PackageUserInformation : {}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7_7.2208.15002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.33519.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok

PS C:\>  Set-AppxPackageAutoUpdateSettings -PackageFamilyName 'SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCoLtd.SamsungNotes_wyx1vj98g3asy' -HoursToPause 4320 -PauseUpdates
Set-AppxPackageAutoUpdateSettings: No se ha encontrado el elemento. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070490)
```

The error translates to `Element not found. (HRESULT exception: 0x80070490)`

Comment: While it is not a solution for my question, for those looking for how to run a current version of Samsung Notes, instead of retaining it from updating, this project worked for me: https://github.com/kellwinr/galaxybook_mask